use a custom order for strings when doing a group by in bigquery
I have a column of ID's and a column of strings. In reality these strings are ordinal however, so when grouping by the ID I would like some method of selecting the maximum of the custom order.
For example say I have



ID
Str




001
banana


001
pear


002
pear


002
apple



such that banana < pear < apple, or apple = 3, pear = 2, banana = 1.
Then I would group by ID selecting the maximum string for each ID according to this ordering.
Select
ID,
max_ordinal(Str)
from table

giving



ID
Column B




001
pear


002
apple



I have tried putting the order into a separate table of strings and values and joining on, but this becomes a mess where I have to join, select max of the value, then re join the string associated.

You can order the data by string in a window function and use rank, see below:
WITH fruit AS (
    SELECT 1 as ID, 'banana' as Str
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 as ID, 'pear' as Str
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 as ID, 'pear' as Str
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 as ID, 'apple' as Str
)

SELECT
    ID,
    Str
from 
    (SELECT
        ID,
        Str,
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Str 
        ) AS rnk
    FROM fruit) where rnk = 1

result:

Another option (BigQuery)
SELECT id, MAX_BY(Str, OFFSET) AS columnB
FROM your_table
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(['banana','pear','apple']) Str WITH OFFSET
USING (Str)
GROUP BY id 

with same output


Use below approach (BigQuery)
SELECT id, MAX_BY(' ' || Str || ' ', STRPOS(' banana pear apple ', Str)) AS columnB
FROM your_table 
GROUP BY id

if applied to sample data in your question  - output is

